# Resizing QWidget to windowSize - buttonSize on Android

Tags: android, qt, user-interface, qwidget, qtablewidget

[image: ScreenShot]

1. I am trying to make the QTableWidget fit the Window Size but leave the space for QPushButton at the bottom.

[image: Proper image]

I tried the following:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

ui->tablieWidget->showMaximized();
```

But they do not seem to be working at all.

2. I want to make the button resize to the text size dynamically

Comment: QWidget is not really designed to work on Android (it will work but not properly and you'll get rendering glitches). You might want to use Qt Quick instead.

Comment: So how am I supposed to make Qt Quick support all the QWidgets (and c++) functionalities work for Qt Quick forms? I've never done anything in Q t Quick Controls but is it possible to add c++ code to such application?